# Nestjs-telegraf with express

Tags: node.js, nestjs, telegraf

i got this error after sending start form the  bot

**/home/kali/repos/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:28
response.status(statusCode);
^
TypeError: response.status is not a function
at ExpressAdapter.reply (/home/kali/repos/api/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:28:22)
**

i recive the chat info but i can not reply to the message

my telegram service is this

```
@Update()
export class TelegramService {
  @Start()
  async start(@Ctx() ctx: Context) {
    await ctx.reply('Welcome');
  }
}
```

i try to send message without using ctx.reply but i got the same error